# cell padding not working with progress bar on table's cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap progress bar on table cells. Everything is working fine except that there is a lot of padding at the bottom making the table unnecessarily tall.

I want to remove the padding from the cell's bottom. I tried making the progress bar smaller and making the cell's padding 0px but still not working the way I want it. How can I shave some of the bottom space?

```
     .progress {
        height: 10px;
    }
        .table > tbody > tr > td{
          padding-top: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;

        }

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Progress</th>
      <th>CustomerID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="10010" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:20%;"> </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>NYC</td>
      <td>123</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="10012" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:30%;"> </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>CT</td>
      <td>1001</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="10013" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%;"> </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>ME</td>
      <td>10013</td>

    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/z6skp8nx/)

I want to remove the padding from the cell's bottom. I tried making the progress bar smaller and making the cell's padding 0px but still not working the way I want it. How can I shave some of the bottom space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.progress` class has a bottom margin of 20px

```
.progress {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Override this in your own CSS

```
.progress {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could get rid of the margin bottom of the progress class:

```
.progress {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/z6skp8nx/